# Replacement for TCT's pcat utility

Tags: rhel, 64bit

I am looking for a utility to dump the memory of a running process that I can then examine for strings.

In the past I have used pcat from The Coroner's Toolkit, but I am having a hard time finding a version that will work on RHEL 6.4 64bit. Given that TCT is in its twilight, is there a better utility to do this?

Edit: I am looking for a utility. I will use scripts to get what is needed if necessary, but I was hoping for a standalone tool that I could get from the standard repo that will allow an untrained user to grab the process's memory.

Comment: One of the answers in the duplicate mentions `gcore`, did you try that one?

Comment: gcore appears to have the memory in it that I am interested in. Add it as an answer and I will accept. Thanks!

Comment: There's no reason to add it, your question has been closed as a duplicate of the other one and one of the answers there mentions `gcore` (I'd never heard of it). Glad you sorted it out.

Answer (score 2):

With `$p` the pid of the process:

```
while IFS='- ' read a b z; do
  dd bs=4096 skip="$((0x${a%???}))" count="$((0x${b%???}-0x${a%???}))" \
    if="/proc/$p/mem" 2> /dev/null > "$a-$b"
done < "/proc/$p/maps"
```

You may want to suspend the process first to get a consistent result.

That dumps every memory region in separate files which you can use `string` on.

Some systems prevent processes to inspect the memory of other processes (even from the same user) by default (see the [kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/security/Yama.txt) for more info).

On those systems, you'll have to run the above as `root` or disable that restriction (not recommended on a permanent basis):

```
sysctl -w kernel.yama.ptrace_scope=0
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work for me. I attempted to use this in a script on a Ubuntu box and it created lots of empty files.

Debugging led to messages about "cannot skip to specified offset" and "No such process" re@ /proc/{pid}/mem.

Comment: @useSticks, what about after issuing a `sysctl -w kernel.yama.ptrace_scope=0`

Comment: I received an error of kernel.yama.ptrace_scope is an unknown key on both the Ubuntu test and RHEL target machines. Thanks for your help though